# Why is my iPhone WIFI so slow at home?

Tags: iphone, wireless-networking

When my iPhone is connected to my home wireless network, the internet is unusably slow.  I installed the speedtest.net application; here are some results from tonight:

- Down: 0.0kB/s, Up: 0.0kB/s, ping: 2230ms
- Down: 2.5kB/s, Up: 40.5kB/s, ping: 2182ms
- Down: 0.0kB/s, Up: 20.0kB/s, ping: 197ms

For comparison, here is the result from my iMac to the same server, which is on the same wireless network (and has no wired connection):

- Down: 139kB/s, Up: 53.8kB/s, ping: 182ms

Neither my iMac nor the Dell laptop also on the network have experienced the wifi problems I get with my iPhone.  On the other hand, I tried browsing a website on the wireless network at work with no problems.

EDIT: SpeedTest at work gives me 156kB/s down.
EDIT2: Girlfriend (owner of the Dell) reports actually the internet is sometimes very slow.  Perhaps there is more going on.  No problems with my iMac.

My router is a  ASUS WL-500g Premium V2 running OpenWrt Kamikaze with X-Wrt Extensions 8.09.

Comment: Where were you, when trying this ? I mean compared to your router. Do you experience same if sitting "next" to it ? Maybe you have weaker antenna in phone, simply, and it can't pass walls like others.

Comment: Just reran the speed test twice when about 2m away from router (no walls).  First time 20kB/s each way, second time 2kB/s each way.

Comment: can you confirm that your iPhone is actually connecting to *your* router and not defaulting to one from someone nearby?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a *last-resort* solution, but have you tried restoring (or upgrading if you haven't) the OS?

I had the same problem when I first got the iPhone. Had slow connection and a weak signal even when I was sitting by the WiFi AP. Had some problems with weak carrier signal too.

I dropped by the store and moaned about it the nice chap there recommended that I restored the OS (using iTunes). I did, and it worked!

**Edit**

Reread the title and just notice the "weak WiFi **at home**" bit. Is you WiFi connection better when using a different access point? The answer might indicate if it's something to do with your phone of your AP.

**Edit 2**

You could also try changing try changing you AP settings to something that suits the iPhone better.

From: http://qelix.com/blog/2008/08/31/get-better-wifi-speeds-on-iphone-3g/

> **Channel ID**: Channel 9 (2452 Mhz)
>
> **Protocol**: 802.11 b (This is the most important bit. 802.11 b works
>   better for iPhone, for some reason)

Comment: I just did that the other day, when the 3.0.1 update failed.  Maybe I'll try again if no one else comes up with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This advice is not specific to the iPhone, but one of the first things I always do when people report one device being slower than others on a home network is **turn off IPv6 everywhere**:

- Turn it off on your router
- Turn it off on your Mac
- Turn it off on your girlfriend's Dell
- Turn it off on your iPhone, if that's possible

A mixed IPv4/IPv6 network with clients/routers that "kind-of" understand IPv6 can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: I don't think the Dell supports IPv6 but I know the mac does.  I will look into this.